# Is there any way to us NTLM authorization in a visual studio .http file?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I have been writing REST API requests using a [.http file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/http-files), however I get a 401 Unauthorized containing the following headers:

```
Content-Length: 0
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
Date: Tue, 30 Jan 2024 20:27:43 GMT
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication
```

Is there any way to do the NTLM negotiation in a .http file? Or am I forced to install Fiddler or Postman?